# i wants to take each row from csv file and store prints outputs while taking for range(10) ValueError: 'nrows' must be an integer >=0

Tags: python, csv

**i wants to take each row from csv file and store prints outputs  while taking for range(10) ValueError: 'nrows' must be an integer >=0**

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
#aaa = pd.read_csv("/content/SolarPrediction_edited.csv", usecols = ['Temperature','Pressure','Humidity','WindDirection(Degrees)','Speed','TSR_Minute','TSS_Minute','TSS_Hour','Month','Day','Hour','Minute','Second','WindDirection(Degrees)_bin','TSS_Minute_bin','Humidity_bin'])
#aaa.to_csv('/content/SolarPrediction_output.csv') 
path="/content/SolarPrediction_output.csv"
#ro=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for x in range(5):
  #print(x)
  if x>0:
    #print(x)
    mydata = pd.read_csv(path,  nrows=x)
    mydata.drop("Unnamed: 0",axis=1,inplace=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
    y_pred = np.array(df)
    #print(y_pred)
    predict=model.predict(y_pred)
print(predict) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-25f39d9afdb3> in <module>()
     10   if x>0:
     11     #print(x)
---> 12     mydata = pd.read_csv(path,  nrows=x)
     13     mydata.drop("Unnamed: 0",axis=1,inplace=True)
     14     df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _validate_integer(name, val, min_val)
    391             val = int(val)
    392         elif not (is_integer(val) and val >= min_val):
--> 393             raise ValueError(msg)
    394 
    395     return val

ValueError: 'nrows' must be an integer >=0
```

Answer (score -1):

**You should try this it will work :-**

```
for x in range(1,6):
```